# What is the difference between these two event declarations?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I have two events in a class

```
public event AcquiredDataEvent OnNewAcquiredData;
public delegate void AcquiredDataEvent(int[] newData);

public ScanStartedEvent ScanStarted;
public delegate void ScanStartedEvent();
```

I just realized that `ScanStarted` does not have the keyword `event` before it. Most likely the result of a typo by me, though it still works as expected.

**What is the difference between the two events if any?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `ScanStarted` is not event. It's just a field of delegate type.
2. It can be invoked outside of class where field is declated.
3. It does not provide add/remove methods (that is what event is, like property is a pair of get/set methods) for attaching/removing event handlers - you can simply assign new delegate to `ScanStarted` field.

BTW Just like you can have property without backing field

```
public int Value
{
   get { return 42; }
   set { Console.WriteLine($"Haha, keep {value} for yourself"); }
}
```

You can have event without delegate field under the hood

```
public event AcquiredDataEvent OnNewAcquiredData
{
   add { Console.WriteLine("Trying to attach some handlers?"); }
   remove { Console.WriteLine("Haha, you should attach something first!"); }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I must look into this. Thank you.

Comment: @KDecker the most important point is - event adds safety to you. You cannot just invoke it like `obj.ScanStarted()` or assign value to it `obj.ScanStarted = YourNewAndOnlyHandler`